# Content going outside the div and into the next div

Tags: html, css

When the content of left div is longer than the right div, then the content of left div goes outside the parent container div and into the next div.

HTML:

```
<div class="musictemplate_container">
    <div class="musictemplate_left">
        something<br>
        omething<br>
        omething<br>
        omething<br>
        omething<br>
        omething<br>
        omething<br>
        omething<br>
    </div>
    <div class="musictemplate_right">
        right1
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.musictemplate_container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.musictemplate_left {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
}

.musictemplate_right {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me. The only instance where it would spill into the adjacent div is a really long word with many characters, forcing it to not break properly. but to avoid the spilling over regardless, you just declare the overflow property:

```
.musictemplate_left {
width: 20%;
float: left;
padding: 30px;
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: But it's not working for me. Please check this screenshot - https://i.ibb.co/Lng2Ngv/gfhgfhghjghj.png
I am using this code in a custom page template for Wordpress.

Comment: Then you must be referring to it vertically overflowing? The height of a div is going to be determined by its content by default. In this case it depends on how the rest of the header is coded so I can't really tell unless you give me more code or post the link to the site